# Div not aligning properly in IE - Works perfectly in Firefox/Chrome

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html

I am trying to align products divs within row divs with 4 inside of it to make it look like a shopping site, it works fine on Chrome and Firefox but seems to stack down the middle overlapping and going out of the div it should stay within. I have tried alot of solutions but none have worked so I need help!

**CSS**

```
#products1 {
width:1000px;
height:320px;
margin:auto;
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom:15px;
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
}

.product {
margin:auto;
height:320px;
width:230px;
border:1px solid #d9d9d9;
position:relative;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #BBB;
display:inline-block;
}
```

The products1 is a div container to hold the 4 products within and the product is 4 boxes within it but only it doesnt work in IE

Answer (score 0):

add "float:left;" inside .product{}

btw u didn't mention which version of IE